# How to load jQuery before fallback in Wordpress footer

Tags: wordpress, scripting, cdn

I enqueue a bunch of scripts into the footer of my page:

```
function core_scripts() { 

    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 

    wp_register_script('jquery', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false, null, true);

    wp_register_script('bootstrap', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.1.1', true);

    wp_register_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), '2.2.2', true); 

    wp_register_script('jqzoom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.jqzoom-core-pack.js', array('jquery'), '2.3', true); 

    wp_register_script('fancybox', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), '2.1.5', true); 
    ... a bunch of others ...
}
add_action('init', 'core_scripts'); // Add Custom Scripts 


function write_site_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
    wp_enqueue_script('jqzoom');
    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox'); 
    ...etc...
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'write_site_scripts'); // write all enqueued scripts

function write_custom_scripts()
{   
    $html = "<!-- Custom script -->
    <script>
    var custom = '1';
    </script>";
    echo $html;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'write_custom_scripts'); // this script writes in the footer before the dependent js scripts
```

My problem is that the custom script is always written to the page before the jQuery scripts, I guess because the custom script is written to the page via an echo write command.

How can I add custom javascript code into the footer after the jQuery scripts have been written to the page? ie. I need to delay the add_action('wp_footer', 'write_custom_scripts'); to be executed at a later moment, or how can I use enqueue to add a custom javascript?

Note I have removed the CDN code posted earlier since this leads everyone into another discussion - a valid one, but it's not the issue I am after at this moment.

Comment: 1. WHY are you doing that ? .. and 2 - wp_footer shoots after wp_enqueue_xx.. and 3 - Why is your fallback a different jQuery and not the one bundled in WP `??

Comment: 1. The default jQuery script is not loaded from a CDN 2. wp_footer may fire after wp_enqueue but the echo writes the code to the page before... this is my problem 3. I should have also stated I need additional javascript to run AFTER the CDN scripts are written to the page and not necessarily the fallback code but it writes to the page before the CDN script

Comment: I know the deafult is not from CDN.. and wp_footer does not echo before . YOur problem is that you are doing that in wrong order , and the aditional script, if you will use dependencies in the enqueue function, will be loaded in the right order . Still do not understand why the CDN though ..

Comment: DO not understand your answer - "YOur problem is that you are doing that in wrong order".. where?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - I want to write some javascript to the page AFTER the jquery file is loaded in the footer of the page. It all works fine if I write to the header, but I need to add the custom js script to the footer at the end of everything else. Ignore the fallback CDN script in the example, since this is confusing and it's not necessarily what I need to do

Comment: You're not going to get that much load time difference for jquery itself, just load the version that comes with WordPress and then you don't have to worry about CDNs going offline.

Comment: Whether I load the jquery from the CDN or not, the issue is that I need to write a javascript script after Wordpress has enqueued the jquery file and it's other file dependencies. This was not a post about the pros and cons of CDN usage - even if I load the files locally through Wordpress, I still have the same issue. The example I gave was a bad one since it has now evolved into another topic of discussion...

Comment: It is not really another topic, because if you will read my answer, you will understand that while enqueueing the right way ( dependencies ) , WP will make sure jQuery will always load before your script . Enqueue. Not Echo.

Comment: I have edited my question to be clearer - let me know how to enqueue a custom script based on the example I have given?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit II**

Since the question has changed in essence many times, and In order to save you from reading ( e.g. - understanding ) all of the long explanation below, just use .

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'write_custom_scripts',9999);
```

This will set the priority to very high and will `probably` echo your code last ( unless you or other plugin / theme developers used a higher priority or later filter ..)

For those who want to do the right way :

```
function my_javascripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('the-script-handle', 
                      'path/to/file.js', 
                      array('jquery','other_script_that_we_depend_on'), 
                      'scriptversion eg. 1.0', 
                      true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_javascripts');
```

When you enqueue a script like above ( the right way ) , you can see that it [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) has 4 arguments.`path`, `dependencies` ,`version` ,and `in-footer` .

This is the only right way to load a script , and if you need , just enqueue also jquery at the same function -- wp will make sure it loads first .

The dependencies means that wp will not load your script UNLESS jQuery is already loaded and will try to load jQuery FIRST ...

The LAST argument will actually define weather to load your script in the FOOTER ( TRUE ) or in header ( FALSE )

That being said , you can always load jQuery in the HEADER and not footer ( but it is not so recommended )

After that , For the last bit of your script , you can echo it in the footer , and you can also control how and when to add it .

What I do not understand , is the overall aim of your method . ( this part is about the "doing it wrong " )

Firstly - I think that loading from CDN is not a good IDEA . AND I AM [NOT ALONE](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/). it is to be considered a bad practice in WP without any meaningful Pros ( the time issue is a joke since you will be probably loading a LOT of other scripts directly AND scripts are Cached ).

While doing it - it is good that you think of a fallback, but the fallback should be wp own version - and not one that you include yourself .

If you still insist on doing it wrong , you can always do something like ( or just change order of execution ):

```
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 9);
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
    // your stuff
        add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
        add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
        add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 5);
```

Which basically allow you to echo your stuff before or after the wp_footer action at will And while technically it will work -. it is still wrong .

**Edit I** After question edit .

you have several problems in that code .

1. you are registering jQuery (CDN ) with the handle `jquery` which is reserved for WP.

If you want to do that ( and you shouldn´t . please don´t ) you need to deregister jquery BEFORE registering it again .

```
<?php wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); ?>
```

Again. I can not stress enough how wrong that is .

2 .  you are registring the whole bunch of script - but where do you enqueue them ?

3 . Again . Like in comments ( I think you still do not understand )

If you have a script to add to the footer - you need to register and enqueue it with dependencies .. ( the right way )

In your case from edited question :

make a file called my_script.js

```
var custom = '1';
```

Enqueue it !

```
wp_enqueue_script('the-script-handle', 
                      'path/to/my_script.js', 
                      array('jquery','other_script_that_we_depend_on'), 
                      '0.0.1', 
                      true);
```

In this case , your script will load AFTER the dependencies you listed ... 
What you are trying to do is echoing directly .

As for the comment of how to correctly pass variables - [read here](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/)

And you can also do something like this ( objects ):

```
$data = (object) array(
  'render' => 'canvas',
  'size' => 100,
  'radius' => ($q_corner_r * 0.3),
);

$output .= 
  <script type="text/javascript">;
   //<![CDATA[

    var options = ' . json_encode($data) . '

   // ]]>;
   </script>';
```

Comment: I actually DO enqueu all my scripts the right way - I had not included this code in the example.

Comment: So please Change the question to the right complete code that produces the alleged problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: Ok understood - I will do this now.

Comment: Looking at your answer I think you may have it solved - by adding the number value to control the order of execution of the scripts. I will try this out, but if you have a better way based on my new example I have provided I am all ears - still interested to know how people write a custom dynamic script into a page that relies on a PHP value hence cannot be included into a separate .js file

Comment: > In your case from edited question make a file called my_script.js ... I cannot do this the var value is custom php code. It cannot reside in a separate javascript file, it is in the functions.php and is dynamically evaluated (my eg was very simplified) - otherwise it would be easy ;) Looking at your 2nd example (objects) I'll take a look at that solution..

Comment: "f you want to do that ( and you shouldn´t . please don´t ) you need to deregister jquery BEFORE registering it again" - I DO deregister the jquery - of course. I just hadn't included the full source for simplification.

Comment: So far all the issues you are pointing out are issues I am doing correctly... I already know how to register degister and enqueue scripts.

Comment: " Did you read the article I have linked ?" I am looking at this now - this looks to have a possible solution :)

Comment: So... back to my original question again... where/how do you write the script $output = ... into the page??